# Define area to animate on hover and move all page content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I need a "special" animation and i am not finding how i will get this sort of animation i seek for, on each triangle should make the same animation, one to the left and one to the right, i need the right way to start making this. Do i use JQuery for this ?

The animation: I want the triangles to move more or less to the middle of screen in order to show the content that is hidden, as it happens here: beepi.com/default.aspx on the circles

I currently have this:

```css
#anim {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/EPM2arR.jpg");
  background-image: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}
#anim img {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.arrow-left {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 1.5% 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: absolute;
  width: 13%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  top: 40%;
}
.arrow-right {
  text-align: right;
  padding: 1.5% 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: absolute;
  width: 13%;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  top: 40%;
}
.arrow-right h2 {
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #FFF;
}
.arrow-left h2 {
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<section id="anim">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/AeCYNqc.png">
  <div class="arrow-right">
    <h2>Scouting For Companies</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="arrow-left">
    <h2>Seeking For Ideas</h2>
  </div>
</section>
```

The animation should be like this:

[image]

Comment: I don't understand which exact animation want you to apply in which triangle. Do you want it to flip? To move (from where to where, in loop...)?

Comment: To move more or less to the middle of screen in order to show the content   that is hidden, as it happens here: https://www.beepi.com/default.aspx on the circles

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, you need css animation. You can use something like this:

```
/* For right side */
.arrow-right{
  animation: aniright 3s ease;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes aniright {
    from { right: 0; }
    to { right:  13%; }
}

/* For left side */
.arrow-left{
    animation: anileft 3s ease;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes anileft {
    from { left: 0; }
    to { left: 13% }
}
```

I believe you will need to cut and put arrows from image in .arrow-left and .arrow-right classes together will all other elements you want to slide in.. and also put some action to call animation. For e.g:

```
.arrow-left:hover{
    animation: anileft 3s ease;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

... will start animation when your cursor goes over .arrow-left element.

Comment: www.beepi.com i want something close to this, only css ?

Comment: @BugaDroid This answer is pure CSS